# What are the seven Moksha granting cities?

Tags: puranas, moksha, reference-request, kashi, ayodhya

In India A Sacred Geography by Diana Eck - it says (p 408)

> The great city of the Rama legend is Ayodhya, known to the Puranas as one of the seven moksha-granting cities of India.

I know Varanasi is one - what are the seven cities and which scriptures mention them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapta_Puri

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Garuda Purana, 16.114:

> He who, expecting to die, leaning his home, dwells at a sacred bathing-place, or dies in a place of liberation, he verily attains liberation.
>
> **Ayodhyā,  Mathurā, Mayā, Kaśī, Kañchi, Avantikā, Dwārāvatī**, --these seven cities should be known as the givers of liberation.

(Kashi is obviously Varanasi)

This is the only scripture, I believe, that discusses these.

Comment: modern names: Ayodhya, Mathura, Haridwar (Maya or Gaya), Varanasi (Kashi), Kanchipuram (Kanchi), Ujjain (Avantika), Dwarka (Dwaravati)….“अयोध्या मथुरा माया काशी कांची अवन्तिका | पुरी द्वारावती चैव सप्तैता मोक्ष दायिका: ||”…

Comment: Is Mayapuri a Haridwar or Gaya?

Comment: @Pandya - I don't understand, sorry. Can you clarify?

Comment: Going my Sanskrit verse of Garuda Purana, it doesn't explicitly mention Gaya. Continuing in chat....

Comment: @Pandya - that's interesting. Does it use the word 'Maya'? [Here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pracheen_Bharatiya_Dharm_Evam_Darshan/xtntNgjz9y8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA151&printsec=frontcover) is one quoted version of the original verse. [This](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/gpu/gpu18.htm#fr_197) is the translation I used.