# Is it true that people who are cremated in Kashi get Moksha?

Tags: moksha, death, kashi, cremation

Is it true that people who are cremated in Kashi get Moksha?
Or, is it people who die in Kashi that get Moksha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dying in Kashi is enough to earn liberation; see [my answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/56098/29157) here. Quoting from the Same Garuda Purana verse, 16.114:

> He who, expecting to die, leaning his home, dwells at a sacred bathing-place, or **dies in a place of liberation, he verily attains liberation.**
>
> Ayodhyā, Mathurā, Mayā, **Kaśī**, Kañchi, Avantikā, Dwārāvatī, --these seven cities should be known as the givers of liberation.

Also, from [Skanda Purana 1.30](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423768.html):

> **One who dies in Kāśī becomes immortal (liberated)** without Nididhyāsana (practice of continuous meditation) of Brahman known only from the Vedāntas, without Sāṅkhya (discrimination between Ātman and non-Ātman) and without Yoga (the practice with ancillaries).

Answer (score 0):

Kaashi is very famous for the Sangamam of river ganga and other tributaries.

Actually the word cremation is not apt. In Kashi, the ashes of Divine COWs after their death must be foresaken as humans feed on Cow milk for immunity anď survival.
Due to human inability to protect Sacred COWS from being hunted or slaughtered forcefully for strength & bones, the protectors (PASHUPAALAKAs) must take holy dip in river ganga or dakshina ganga (rivers - originating from SHIRA of PASHIPATHINAATH) often to save them from multiple births. In old ages due to physical immobility of not visiting ganges river for HOLY BATH, they wish their ashes be foresaken to ganges instead of OCEANS.

The principles are not applicable to a sect of Vegans within Vegetarian community and old persons who had their PRAPATTI done from Vaishnava Aacharya of Holiness.